# Is it possible to change the name of generated makefile in CMake?

Tags: makefile, cmake

I have a project which uses Makefiles. On a branch, I have CMake based build system. Now some team-members wants the OLD make-files based system intact, when cmake is added. But this is not possible after `cmake .` command overwrites the old Makefile.

Now I can easily avoid it if I can tell CMake to generate makefiles with some non-standard names e.g. `makefile.cmake` etc. Is it possible?

I am open to consider other options as well. In any case, old Makefiles must not be touched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cmake creates a build system in the working directory. So create any empty directory, and run `cmake <path-to-source>` from there.

Comment: It did the job. Thanks. Will wait for few days just to see if changing the name of makefiles are possible.

Comment: I was lazy and did "mkdir build; cd build; cmake .." without removing the output of previous "cmake" commands. Files such as cmake_install.cmake were still in the ".." directory so the output of "cmake .." went to ".." instead of build. I would guess that OP was not lazy like I was.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the name "Makefile" in hard-coded several times, in the sources of CMake. You cannot change it. As Peter has pointed out [in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23363403/1728537), that change is not necessary, because CMake support out-of-source builds.